# Weather difference on Mars compared to Earth

Tags: astronomy, meteorology

How the weather on Mars differs from here on Earth? In [here](http://www.space.com/1582-earth-mars.html) you see that weather on Earth is

> Hurricanes, typhoons and tornadoes a real problem. Disgustingly interminable fog in coastal California. Utter lack of rain in parts of Africa. Way too wet in many other places.

I have hard time reading what is said about weather on Mars, because it can't be read on my browser.
What about temperature; is it truth that temperature reaches never +23 celcius even on Mars equator?
Is it true that weather here on Earth is more complex than on Mars or on any other bigger celestial bodies(moons, planets) with atmosphere in solar system?

The reason I ask this is because of the notion that there are many kind of weather phenomena in Earth, so I guess that weather here is more complex that any other body in Solar system.

Comment: Don't think this is related to physics.

Comment: @mikhailcazi. It is question on meteorology.

Comment: The FAQ says "Physics Stack Exchange is for active researchers, academics and students of physics and **astronomy**." (emphasis mine) Despite not being well advertised this is actually on topic.

Comment: Oh, okay then...

Comment: This is a conceptual question, not direct exercise question

Comment: laovultai, this is still a very broad question. Please also consider getting another browser. And yes, presence of liquid water makes weather quite diverse.

Comment: @laovultai you can probably read this because it is mostly text:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Mars

Comment: (1) Yes, there are some on-topic points here, but (2) this is indeed quite broad, asking for a summary of an entire *planet's* weather. (3) Still, we can do better. That site isn't 100% reliable - there seems to be a bias toward hoping Mars is colonizable. (4) If your browser doesn't display what's on that page, your browser is ***broken***, and you should really fix that issue before asking us to retype what is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at all a climate specialist, so this is more suggestions based on
my understanding of the problem.

If you search the web, you will find a lot of information about the
weather on various planets and satellites. [Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Mars) is probably the best
known outside Earth.

Regarding complexity of the climate and the weather, there are
probably many factors to consider. One is the complexity of the
surface material. The presence of water ocean on Earth, and the water
cycles probably increase considerably the complexity of Earth climate.
You do not have that on Mars (any longer), but you have it on [Titan](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/cassini/whycassini/cassini20130522.html) with methane
oceans, and methane playing the role of water.

Another factor is probably the energy available to run a complexe
climate. There is probably more energy available on [Venus](http://www.space.com/18527-venus-atmosphere.html) or [Jupiter](http://www.universetoday.com/15132/weather-on-jupiter/)
for different reasons, though the Earth is well situated for that.
Titan is probably losing on this account.

And, of course, the big gas giants, like Jupiter, probably have a very
complex atmosphere simply because of the size of their atmosphere.

But the weather of mars is complex and energetic enough. Weather on
the Moon is a lot more predictable, except for [particle storms](http://www.theweathernetwork.com/news/articles/nasa-sun-eruption-to-send-particle-storm-toward-earth/11411/) from
the Sun, as no atmosphere or magnetic field will protect you.

These are suggestions, but you should make your opinion by studying
the information available on the web.

Comment: well, man is curious, but this comparison makes other planets more near to me.